# Transaction committed successfully but didn't end

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, commit

We have serious problem in our Stored Procedures with transactions.

Take this scenario:

```
Beging trans
Declare cursor
read cursor & insert in second table
close cursor
dellocate cursor
commit trans
select 'ok'
```

When we run this sample SP it shows OK record which means transaction committed successfully, but we found that sometimes the transaction continues after commit and locks related tables, and if related session killed in activity monitor, SQL understand it as rollback.

How we could end transaction after commit?

Comment: `Beging trans`? `dellocate`?

Comment: Sounds like your code has created a nested transaction and the commit only decrements the transaction counter leaving the transaction open. You will need to debug your code more thoroughly.

Comment: I mean our transaction didn't run in loop,why nested transaction created.